# Groovy to Json in Controller

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I am a novice in groovy but I have to create POGO for future transforming it online to json with Controller.

I can not understand is Groovy use something underhood or I have to explicity handle every my transforms?

For example, I got request to Controller and I have to make any method which would transform to my POGO? And after my prepared answer in POGO can I send my Object or have to transform to JSON?

Because in Spring, as I known, everything is underhood.

Also, I have something like

```
class SearchRequest extends Result{
  private Source source
  private String executorSystem
}
```

but in JSON executorSystem should be executor_system. How could I do it without jackson?

Comment: If you are asking how to bind a JSON attribute named `executor_system` to a property named `executorSystem`?

Comment: I have several questions and this is one of them